# how to create a rank with data on firebase using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create a rank type for my application to list the most qualified products. Any idea?

my firebase

```
products-
| id--
|  |  liked:2
|  |  name: x
| id--
|  |  liked:1
|  |  name: y
| id--
|  |  liked:3
|  |  name: z
```

my application

```
X 2
y 1
z 3
```

i need

```
z 3
X 2
y 1
```

I found this. 
Used to invert the

```
var ref = new Firebase('https//buzzg**.firebaseio.com/comments');
query = ref.orderByChild('timestamp');
comments = []; 
query.once('value', function(snap) { 
    snap.forEach(function(ss) { 
      comments.push(ss.val()); 
    }); 
    comments = comments.reverse(); 
 });
```

but i don't know implement. because of error in function(ss) inside into (foreach)

Comment: In general, using orderBy:liked would order them 1, 2, 3. If you want descending order, just store your liked as negative values so they will load -3, -2, -1. Or if you have a smaller dataset, sort them in code.

Comment: I found this.
Used to invert the list.

Comment: var ref = new Firebase('https//buzzg**.firebaseio.com/comments'),
    query = ref.orderByChild('timestamp'),
    comments = [];

query.once('value', function(snap) {

  snap.forEach(function(ss) {
    comments.push(ss.val());
  });

  comments = comments.reverse();
});

Comment: but i don't know implement.
because of error in function(ss) inside into (foreach)

Comment: Please put your code in your question as it's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: I solved what you said.
Registering with -1, -2, -3.
And at the time of listing I multiplied by -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.rankedItems$ = this.angularfireDatabase.list('products')
  .map(products => products.sort((a, b) => b.liked - a.liked));
```

This will give you an observable of arrays, each of which contains `{liked, name}` objects, sorted by `liked` in descending order. You can use this in your template as follows:

```
<h3>Products ranked by likes</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of rankedItems$ | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, you could do

```
this.angularfireDatabase.list('products', {query:
  orderByChild: 'liked'
}};
```

but this is limited to sorting in ascending order.

Comment: i cannot implement because of error in .map()
he talk 'map not a function'

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map;`